# Unhandled exception when a TextBox is cleared

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I getting a FormatException was unhandled error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312411/why-am-i-getting-a-formatexception-was-unhandled-error)

I am new to C# and Stack Overflow, so if this question is inappropriate (or in the wrong place) feel free to edit or remove it.

I've made a simple calculator, but I have a problem: when I clear one of the textboxes to enter another number a message shows saying *"Unhandled exception occured"* with the option to quit or continue. How can I stop this message from displaying every time I clear the texboxes?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int value1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    int value2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
    textBox3.Text = sum(value1, value2).ToString();
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int vlera1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
}

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int vlera2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
}

private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ }

int sum(int value1, int value2) {
    return (value1) + (value2);
}
```

Comment: why you use vlera1 and vlera2?(why do you need them?)

Comment: @JonSkeet I saw that but I can't relate it to my problem. :(  .

Comment: @hekri: Why not? It's exactly the same problem: whenever the text is changing, you're unconditionally calling `Convert.ToInt32`, which is like calling `int.Parse`. The exact same solutions apply. (It's not clear why you're performing conversions in methods and then discarding the results anyway, but...)

Comment: @SirwanAfifi I think I'm getting what the user inputs in the texbox and asigning it to a variable (vlera1). Like I said I'm new to this thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll receive a `FormatException` when you try to convert a string that can not be converted to a struct of type `int` to `int`. You may always use `int.TryParse(string s, out int result)` to see if the `string` is capable for `int` conversion before doing the conversion.

**Example**

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = 0; //Initialize a new int of name x and set its value to 0
    if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out x)) //Check if textBox1.Text is a valid int
    {
        int vlera1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); //Initialize a new int of name vlera2 and set its value to (textBox1.Text as int)
    }
    else
    {
        //DoSomething if required
    }
}

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = 0; //Initialize a new int of name x and set its value to 0
    if (int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out x)) //Check if textBox2.Text is a valid int
    {
        int vlera2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);  //Initialize a new int of name vlera2 and set its value to (textBox1.Text as int)
    }
    else
    {
        //DoSomething if required
    }
}
```

### **Another Solution**

You may always use a try-catch statement to see if an exception was thrown from the code you provide and do something if required

**Example**

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int vlera1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); //Initialize a new int of name vlera2 and set its value to (textBox1.Text as int)
    }
    catch (Exception EX)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(EX.Message); //(not required) Show the message from the exception in a MessageBox
    }
}

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int vlera2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);  //Initialize a new int of name vlera2 and set its value to (textBox1.Text as int)
    }
    catch (Exception EX)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(EX.Message); //(not required) Show the message from the exception in a MessageBox
    }
}
```

**Notice**: The try-catch statement consists of a try block followed by one or more catch clauses, which specify handlers for different exceptions

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: No thank you Picrofo EGY.  This was very helpful

Answer (score 3):

Use `int.TryParse(string s, out int result)` instead of `Convert.ToInt32(string value, int fromBase)`
this is happening because you are trying to convert the empty data of the `TextBox` to `Int32`.

```
if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out vlera1))
{
    //assign here    
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Ravidra Bagale but when I what you said an error shows up,  "cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'int'".